# assignment and comparing in one expression

Tags: php, expression, variable-assignment

guys.
I have following block of code:

```
$a = true;

if($a === $b = true)
{
    echo 'ok';
}
```

this script give result "ok";

But according to
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php the precedence of the "===" operator is higher than 
precedence of "=". And this expression $a === $b = true should be similar to ($a === $b) = true
So i expected that fatal error should be thrown.
My question is: Why doesn't it produce fatal error? i`am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation you will find following note:

> ### Note:
>
> Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still 
>   allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the > return value of foo() is put into $a.

So in your statement $b is assigned true before the comparsion with $a.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. The documentation is not wrong, but there's a special case here that has higher priority than operator precedence.

Within an if-statement, PHP parses assignments before comparisons, because it needs to know the result of the assignment to be able to compare it to the rest of the expression.

If your if-statement were parsed according to operator precedence, you'd end up with:

```
if ($a === $b = true)
-> if (($a === $b) = true)
-> fatal error because PHP would not be able to store the result of the assignment
```

The left-hand side of the assignment **must** point to a memory address where PHP can store the result. Basically, left of the `=` must be a variable name. Since the rules of operator precedence would break that (more important) rule in your if-statement, PHP *actually* parses your if-statement as follows:

```
if ($a === $b = true)
-> if ($a === ($b = true))   // now the assignment is valid
-> if ($a === true)
-> if (true === true)
-> if (true)
```